# How do I put two tables together in sql

Tags: sql

I have a driver table with ID, Car model, and Fastest Lap columns and would like to put that together with the Car table which has  Car model, Horse power and cost columns. And I want my big table to have Id, Car model, fastest lap, Horsepower, Cost columns.

Comment: It is called a basic join. Please take a SQL tutorial first.

Comment: By using JOIN clause.

Answer (score 1):

It's an easy `JOIN` which might look like

```
SELECT * FROM "driver" JOIN "Car" on (driver.model = car.model)
```

Of course, car.model and driver.model needs to be the same. Ideal your connection is based upon a foreign key constraint. As stated in comments, a basic SQL tutorial is giving you some input here.

Comment: Please, answering these type of questions will only encourage them to post more. This community is not meant for tutorials.

Comment: Was thinking about but decided "gtfo n00b" is maybe also a bad idea as it destroys all motivation.

Comment: I've done this                                                $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT FROM "Driver" JOIN "Car" ON (Driver.Car_model = Car.Car_model) ");  But i get parse error

Comment: Please quote your PHP code correctly and adjust query to your database layout. Please read documentation.